# Use Google Access Token from another origin API

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I need to access to a ASP.net Core API store on Google App Engine from a web page using Google API JS .

For Example :
I've got this script that use Localstorage to store the generated access token

```
function onSignIn(googleUser) {
        var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
        var token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
        LocalStorage.setItem("accessToken", token);
        DisplayValues2();
    }

function DisplayValues2() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:49389/api/values',
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    'content-type': 'application/JSON',
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem("accessToken")
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#divSuccess').text("");
                    $('#divSuccess').text(data);
                    $('#divSuccess').show('fade');
                },
                error: function (jQXHR) {
                    if (jQXHR.status == "401") {
                        $('#errorModal').modal('show');
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#divErrorText').text(jQXHR.responseText);
                        $('#divError').show('fade');
                    }
                }
            });
        };
```

**here the LocalHost:49389 it's just the project that will be push on App Engine*

From my `http://Localhost:59638/login.html` (with the script above) I want to access to the `http://localhost:49389/api/values` API

My Asp.net Core project is on VS2017 with ASP.Net Core On Google Cloud Platform Web API template.

ValuesController :

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ValuesController : Controller
    {
        // GET api/values
        [HttpGet]
        [Authorize]
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2", "value3", "value4", "value5" };
        }
}
```

The only thing that change after created the project is the `[Authorize]` attribute and I receive a :

> 500 internal server error

And I would like to know,

> what should I implement to authenticate the Google token sent in the HTTP header with this API?

Thx

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Thx, I've change the request and add more samples. Is that clearer ?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you will need to do is to ensure that you are telling the authorize to accept a bearer token

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer")]
```

Second is your going to have to make sure that you have the api setup to validate authentication against googles OAuth server.